# Brazing rebar not heating enough

Tags: welding, rebar

I'm attempting to braze together two pieces of rebar. I'm using a Bernzomatic ts8000 torch and MAP-Pro gas, and I just can't seem to get it hot enough (aiming for a red glow). I've had the torch on the spot for several minutes, which seems out of line with what I've seen on various youtube videos. I notice also that it seems to take quite some time to melt the brazing rod - my expectation is that this would be fairly quick ala electronics soldering.

A few possibly relevant points:

- I'm outside on a warm day, with a very slight breeze.
- The rebar is laying on a paving stone, and I'm aiming the torch flame/nozzle roughly downward at the junction.
- I've experimented with the gas flow knob & distance, but have been generally using a fairly high flow rate at a distance of a few inches from the surface.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: That rebar is a lot thicker than electronic stuff.  Would take it to local garage and have them do it with their torch.  Will save money from buying MAP.

Comment: @crip659 This is a practice piece, but I’ll need to do these on-site once I get past this issue. I expect the rebar to be slow to heat, but not the brazing rod!

Comment: Depending on how many/much you do, will need to add oxygen to the MAP.  Most torch makers have small sets that you can use oxygen plus another gas for small/tiny jobs.  For larger job, probably better to go with an oxygen/acetylene set, they come with small, medium, and large tanks.

Comment: if it's borderline hot enough, insulate the rebar with steel wool to reduce it's ability to carry away heat from the torch. Might also be able to pre-heat the bars with a hot air gun or blow torch for several minutes before re-attempting, so that there isn't as large a thermal diff between the bars en masse and the spots to the joined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer turns out to be torch distance. I had previously been placing the work piece mid-flame (perhaps 4 inches from the nozzle). When I moved it into the blue part of the flame, as close as I could come to the nozzle without being in danger of bumping the work piece, it heated right up to a nice cherry red.

I did experiment with doing this on the edge of the paving (low surface area for heat sink), flat on the paving stone as before, and from below, and while the other factors may help, torch distance was the primary factor.

Answer (score 5):

It appears you do not have enough heat energy available. MAPP gas can be used in combination with oxygen for brazing but it appears you do not have the oxygen part. Generally oxygen/acetylene or air/acetylene have enough heat to braze.

Comment: You'll need an acetylene / oxygen torch to get enough heat, like Gil said.

Answer (score 2):

The paving stone is acting as a heat sink, pulling heat out of the rebar. The more bar you have in contact with the stone, the more heat it's pulling out.

I'd suggest having the portion to be brazed hanging in the air. Put another paver below to protect whatever is underneath it (as necessary), and clamp the rebar to the paver to prevent it from falling off.

I doubt this will be a complete solution, but it might just be enough to get it hot enough and is a very cheap option to try before spending money on more tools.

Comment: And heat it from below, not from above.

Comment: @MTA that _sounds_ reasonable, but I'm not quite sure why. Please expand on that, possibly writing it up as your own answer.

Comment: I actually tried that first - clamping to that metal table (talk about heat sink) to no avail. My thought with the stone was that it would help reflect some of the heat back (and remove table contact).

Comment: No need for a complete answer, just an add-on to your correct answer. Based on experience with oxy-acetylene, air-acetylene and propane, heating anything from below, even when using direct flame impingement, is quicker and more effective than heating from above. I'm sure it has something to do with hot air rising and surrounding the upper parts of an object when you heat from below. Heating from above, hot air is more likely to go straight up from the object and not circulate below it. In this particular case with barely enough heat for the job, quick heating is essential.